# MediaWiki anti-bot coding

Tags: php, mediawiki, anti-bot

I want to modify MediaWiki handling of user registration to add an anti bot check.

It looks like the `addNewAccountInternal()` method in the `includes/SpecialUserlogin.php` file is the right place to do it.

The problem is that nothing I change in that file seems to make any difference. Not even removing that file. I didn't install any kind of cache in the server.

I have already written the client side JavaScript code in the `includes/templates/Userlogin.php` file and it works as expected.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same file exists in `includes/specials` and there the modifications work.